# How to alter hbase table description as to make it readonly=>'false'

Tags: hbase

As title says, I need to make my table's description as readonly=>false. How can I achieve that? I can make my table readonly by this line `alter 'mytable', READONLY='true'|'false'' as documentation says but when I says describe 'mytable', it does not say as readonly=>'false'. How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting readonly:

```
alter 'test',{METHOD=>'table_att', READONLY=>true}
```

Unsetting readonly:

```
alter 'test',{METHOD=>'table_att_unset', NAME=>READONLY}
```